# How to re-run vim auto-indentation on a tex file?

Tags: vim, editors, latex

I have a LaTeX source file with its indentation messed up.
I am looking for a way to force vim (may be through one of `vim-latex-suite` commands) to **re-run** the automatic indentation commands over the whole file once again.

I can easily get rid of the messed up indentation by eating up all the white spaces in the beginning of each line with a simple regex `:%s/^\s\+//`. My problem is how to re-run the automatic indentation commands over the whole file.

( I am basically looking for something like the `smart indent` in MATLAB Editor or some other text editor, which can re-indent already existing text).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Method #1: vim

I believe you can do what you want with the following keyboard commands in `vim`, as follows.

**NOTE:** `=`, the indent command can take motions.

So:

- `gg` to get the start of the file
- `=` to indent
- `G` to the end of the file

Putting it all together: `gg=G`.

#### Method #2: without vim

This isn't a `vim` solution but I came across this Perl script titled `LaTeXTidy.pl` which might be more useful if you have multiple files you have to do this with.

The original script and a copy on pastebin:

- http://bfc.sfsu.edu/LaTeXTidy-0.31.pl
- http://pastebin.com/p7vV0Gma

#### Example

To run it you'll need to make it executable after downloading it and then just run it passing it the name of a latex file.

*download*

```
$ curl -o latextidy.pl http://bfc.sfsu.edu/LaTeXTidy-0.31.pl
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4755  100  4755    0     0   1201      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--  1334
```

*permissions and running*

```
$ chmod +x latextidy.pl
$ ./latextidy.pl <some_latex_file.tex>
```

Comment: Your vim suggestion works pretty well and the perl script is really powerful. Thanks ...

Comment: @Bichoy - Glad to hear they were helpful.

Answer (score 4):

In vim the `=` key can be used to automatically fix indentation. `gg=G` will fix the indentation for the entire file.